# How to turn off VelocityViewResolver errors in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, velocity

I'm using Velocity and Spring.  Within Spring, I'm using the `VelocityViewResolver` paired with the `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`.  For the most part, this works great.  The only problem is that the `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` queries the `VelocityViewResolver` with many different content sets (as it should).

When the Velocity engine doesn't find the particular template, an error is produced similar to the following:

> 2011-02-04 13:37:15,074 ERROR [http-8080-2] VelocityEngine: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'foo.json.vm' in any resource loader.

This is not ideal.  Ideally, if a template isn't found, a warning or something similar would be produced.  If a template doesn't exist for a particular content type, I don't really care... as that means that content type isn't supported through that view resolver.

Any idea on how I could suppress this error though the `VelocityViewResolver`, `VelocityView`, or `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`?

Comment: VelocityViewResolver javadoc says: "When chaining ViewResolvers, a VelocityViewResolver always needs to be last, as it will attempt to resolve any view name, no matter whether the underlying resource actually exists". Maybe you can subclass VelocityViewResolver and override buildView(String viewName) so you can check if the view exists and if not then you can change the viewName to the "Not-Found" vm view name and call super.buildView(viewName). It's just an idea if it helps.

Comment: Just as a note, I'm using Spring 3.0, and it looks like the implementation changed a bit: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/VelocityViewResolver.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found that the best way to do this was to add a `logger` statement to my log config file specifically for the Velocity engine (Velocity and my project both use Commons logging).  My logger statement looks like this:

```
<logger name="org.apache.velocity.app">
    <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem will be fixed in Spring 3.2, see [SPR-8640](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8640?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel). After this improvement you will be able to configure Velocity view resolver to check unresolved views only once.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` uses `VelocityViewResolver`. You can stop it from doing that by giving it an empty (but non-null) list of view resolvers.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    ...
    <property name="viewResolvers">
          <list />
    </property>
</bean>
```